# what does endpoint.ex file do in phoenix elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to elixir and phoenix, and using phoenix guides. In getting started guide they just say http://puu.sh/klblD/e50082298d.png but they didn't explain what is endpoint and whats is tasks. Can somebody explain whats it does?

Comment: There is a description in the documentation for the module: http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html

Comment: You should quote the docs as an answer :D

Comment: I added @Gazler 's link as an answer for others who may find this question in the future.

Comment: @JoséValim you are right guides should also have a summary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not to take anything away from @Gazier but I agree with @JoseValim; his response should be an answer so others who might look for this can find it easily.

> The endpoint is the boundary where all requests to your web
>   application start. It is also the interface your application provides
>   to the underlying web servers.
>
> Overall, an endpoint has three responsibilities:
>
> - to provide a wrapper for starting and stopping the endpoint as part
>     of
>     a supervision tree;
> - to define an initial plug pipeline where requests are sent through;
> - to host web specific configuration for your application.

The documentation is [here](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html).